# Angular rotation where radius is unknown

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, classical-mechanics

A light inextensible string AB of length 90 cm has a particle of mass 600 g fastened to it at a point C. The ends A and B are attached to two fixed points in the same vertical line as each other, with A 60 cm above B. The particle moves on a horizontal circle at a constant angular speed of 5 rad/s with both parts of the string taut and CB horizontal. Find the tensions in the two parts of the string.

Resolving vertically $T_1sin\theta=mg=0.6g$

Resolving horizontally $T_2+T_1cos\theta=mr\omega^2=15r$

How can I find the radius given the total string length of 90cm?

[unknown 'r'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOISU.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the distances $AC$ and $CB$ then you can form the triangle $\triangle ABC,$
and the radius you want is the distance of $C$ from the side $AB.$

Since the problem statement says the total length of the string is $90$ and both parts are taut, you have $AC + CB = 90.$
You also have $CB$ horizontal, which tells you that $CB = r$
and that $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle.
(Remember what the Pythagorean Theorem says about a right triangle.)

Can you draw the triangle and find the answer from here?

Comment: I`ve included an image, where $T_2$ acts along the radius.  I looked at saying the hypotenuse was $0.9-r$, which in turn gives $tan\theta=\frac{0.6}{r}$, but I`m still no closer to solving it.

Comment: How would I solve the 2 resolution equations with 2 forces in the horizontal resolution?

Comment: I have 2 equations and 3 unknowns

Comment: Solve for the radius first. The radius depends just on the given statements about the total length of the string, the right angle at $B,$ and the fact that the string is stretched straight. The exact amount of tension in each part, the weight of the particle--those are all irrelevant to the radius. Try drawing a figure without all that stuff so you have room to label it with the things that matter for this step of the solution, such as the unknown $r$ and the known total $90.$ I've added a bit more detail in the answer.

Comment: I just applied pythagoras and and found the radius to be 25cm and hyp 65cm.  Then tension I then found were T2=1.375N and T1=6.175N.  The book however say 1.3N and 6.37N ( Understanding Mechanic, Sadler &  Thorning 1996)

Comment: This is verging on a new question (to solve for tension), but $\sin\theta=13/12$ (hypotenuse over opposite), and if $g=9.8$ I get $T_1 = 6.37$ too.

Comment: I figured out my mistake, but thanks for connecting the dots

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
T_1\sin\theta &=mg\\
T_2+T_1\cos\theta &=mr\omega^2
\end{align}
that is
\begin{align}
T_1&=\frac{mg}{\sin\theta }\\
T_2+mg\cot\theta &=mr\omega^2
\end{align}

Putting $AC=\ell$, $CB=r$, $\ell+r=90\textrm{ cm}$, $AB=h=60\textrm{ cm}$, from $h^2+r^2=\ell^2=(90-r)^2$ we have $r=25\textrm{ cm}$ and $\ell=65\textrm{ cm}$

So we have $\sin\theta=\frac{h}{\ell}$, $\cot\theta=\frac{r}{h}$

\begin{align}
T_1&=\frac{mg}{\sin\theta }=\frac{mg\ell}{h}=6,37\mathrm{ N}\\
T_2&=mr\omega^2-\frac{mgr}{h}=1,3\mathrm{ N}
\end{align}